# MySQL Transitive Dependency

Tags: mysql, transitive-dependency

I'm looking for the wide-ranging clarification of what the Transitive Dependency is. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In short it means that if you can use a to lookup b, and you can use b to lookup c, then you can use a to lookup c.